# What have been the major milestones in the creation of state literacy policies?

Tags: europe, china, education

There have been times as literacy was not obligatory. So, many people were not able to read/write in their mother tongue, but it was just normal.

Today, most people are literate, and this is a result of mandatory state policies as far as I know in most countries on planet Earth.

The state alone has not created literacy, but today it's a state policy.

What are the milestones in the creation of state literacy policies?

From what I can read on Wikipedia, it addresses the history of literacy itself but I do not see there references to state policies.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literacy) on the topic, (particularly since it invalidates your assumption). This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: [Compulsory public education](https://education.findlaw.com/education-options/compulsory-education-laws-background.html) may be useful or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_education) for [China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_education_in_China)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace a short review but helpful! Thank you. What about China?

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are referring to compulsory education.

By and large, compulsory education appears to be a *trailing* indicator of heavy literacy, not a leading one. In other words, once a critical mass of people in a society become literate, it becomes seen as a necessity to function in society (either for the child, for society, or a combination of the two, I think is up for debate).

There's a really nice [interactive graph of world literacy rates](https://ourworldindata.org/literacy) at Our World In Data that I've screenshotted at 1870 below.

[image]

Why 1870? This is not only the first year we have data for the US, but also one of the last datapoints before a lot of the nations on this graph began compulsory education. Specifically, for the 5 countries that gave data that year graph, the [compulsory education enactment timeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_education#Timeline_of_introduction_of_compulsory_education) was:

- The USA enacted it by state. The [only states that had CE in 1870](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED119389.pdf)<sup>(PDF)</sup> were Massachusetts, DC, and Vermont.
- Scotland made education compulsory in 1872. England and Wales didn't have it until 1880.
- France made it compulsory in 1882.
- Sweden made it compulsory 1842.
- Italy got it in 1869

So of the 5 countries listed on that graph popup, only Italy had yet to achieve at least 2/3rds of their citizens literate *before* compulsory education was enacted. Sweden was the first of the 5 to enact it, but it was also already the most literate of the 5 at the date it did so.

Comment: awesome! what about China?

Comment: @J.Doe - From the link I gave, it looks like China didn't have CE until the early 1980's (yes, that's no typo. That's meant to be a '9'). The assorted graphs I'm finding online (I don't know how trustworthy they are) seem to indicate their adult literacy was right at 2/3rds at that time, and is somewhere north of  95% now.

Comment: So (theorizing here) perhaps around 2/3rds is the point where a society has reached a critical mass of literacy to the point where its deemed necessary?

Comment: 2/3 even if that could be some kind of "nature law for literacy", it's interesting to learn what were the triggers that some powerful people have realized that and decided that it's could be of use (instead of thinking the opposite for example)

Comment: Italy is kind of a special case: as a country it started existing only in 1861, and before that Piedmont-Sardinia already had compulsory education. Essentially they tried to extend the system to the whole peninsula without modifications, which worked ok-ish in the North (which was after all rather similar to Piedmont) but horribly in the South (especially leaving the funding to the local municipalities just straight up didn't work in the much poorer South).

Comment: @DenisNardin - Unfortunately that dataset has no data points for Italy between that one and 1981 (where they were at 97%, looking like pretty much any other European Nation). So the data at least can't give us a clue as to if CE on its own had a big effect on literacy in a majority-illiterate nation.

Comment: With regards to Sweden: yes somewhere around 70 % could read, but how good ?

It is also something else with regards to writing. The differences between Stockholm (which was and is the most prosperous conurbation in Sweden) is also pronounced.

Comment: One reason to the large literacy early was the demand that a grown up married man had to be able to educate the childreen in the Bible and Luther's postilla (katekes.)  Not well versed enough at reading ??? No marriage for you until you master this examination.